# How to store an array into a plist file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an array, and I want to store that array into a plist file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have a variable `urArray` holding the array and an `NSString` variable called `pListFilePath` that holds the complete path name of the file you want to create, then this will do it:

```
[urArray writeToFile:pListFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: @7KV7: thanks.. i have an NSDictionary how can i store this array into that NSDictionary...

Comment: I think you can initialize the dictionary from the plist file that you just created

Comment: `NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; `

Comment: @7KV7:I have initilized the NSDicitionary but how can i save that array into the NSDicitionary...

Comment: You transferred the array to the plist file and then u read from the file to dictionary so you have the array in the dictionary.....

Comment: Apple recommends using URLs instead of file paths.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this steps:for `NSArray` store into plist

Example : `arrResult` is your array

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dict1 setValue:arrResult forKey:@"Result"];
[dict1 writeToFile:[self plistPath] atomically:YES]; 
 [dict1 release];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict1 setValue:txtUserName.text forKey:@"username"];
    [dict1 setValue:txtPassword.text forKey:@"password"];
    [dict1 writeToFile:[self plistPath] atomically:YES]; 
    [dict1 release];
```